# How to make my querySelector from array to chain with HTML select options

Tags: javascript, http, selectors-api

```
const endpoint = 'http://api.fixer.io/latest';


var currencies =['EUR','USD','AUD','BGN','BRL','CAD','CHF','CNY','CZK','DKK','GBP','HKD','HRK','HUF','IDR','ILS','INR','JPY','KRW','MXN','MYR','NOK','NZD','PHP','PLN','RON','RUB','SEK','SGD','THB','TRY','ZAR'];

var cur = document.getElementById('CurrencyList');
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
currencies.forEach(function(currency, index){
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = currency;
    opt.value = currency;
    fragment.appendChild(opt);

});

cur.appendChild(fragment);

var cur2 = document.getElementById('CurrencyList2');
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
currencies.forEach(function(currency, index){
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = currency;
    opt.value = currency;
    fragment.appendChild(opt);

});

cur2.appendChild(fragment);

        currencies = document.querySelectorAll('.my-selector');
        Array.from(currencies).forEach(function(el) {
        console.log(el);
});


        function moneyConvert(){

                fetch(endpoint) 
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    const Amount = data.rates.$id;
                    console.log(Amount);
                    const first = currencies.value;
                    console.log(first);
                    const second = (first * Amount).toFixed(2);
                    currencies.value = second;

           });
        }

        document.querySelector(".convertButton").addEventListener("click", moneyConvert);
        currencies.addEventListener("input", moneyConvert);
```

I am learning JavaScript but I choose a bit difficult project money exchange I need to make that currencies array string from that URL to choose in html. I know this may look bizarre but i think from building you learn. I select and option from the array above to choose from the first and second input selector.
Now i need to chain from the API to the string and that string to the inputs.
If this all is wrong please give me guidance how to approach the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Currency App</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>



    <div class="container">
        <h1>Currency Conversion </h1>
        <p>Enter your amount in Euro to see how much it is Pounds</p>
        <div class="conversionWrapper">
            <div class="inputWrapper">
                <select id="CurrencyList"></select>
                <input type="number" name="my-selector'" class="my-selector'" placeholder="0.00" step="0.01" />
            </div><!-- .inputWrapper -->
            <div class="inputWrapper">
                <p>TO</p>
                <select id="CurrencyList2"></select>
                <input type="number" name="my-selector'" class="my-selector'" placeholder="0.00" step="0.01" disabled />
            </div><!-- .inputWrapper -->
            <button class="convertButton">Convert</button>
        </div><!-- .conversionWrapper -->
    </div><!-- .container -->




            <!-- Other Controllers/ Modules / Factories -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[This is the image screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1q8E.jpg)
Those are the two inputs and two selectors i need to chain selector to input

Comment: You need to run this page from a server. Can be a localhost server you set up on your computer. Ajax requests are blocked in `file://` protocol for security reasons

Comment: @charlietfl depends on the browser. Emir, your code doesn't look half bad but when you say "chain", do you mean "depend on the value of"? I am not sure I understand.

Comment: The currencies string array is the data from the URL for currency that array i have to send to HTML which i did, then I have to accept what i choose from HTML selector element to be From which currency and how much to what currency @AluanHaddad

Comment: OK, that seems reasonable. What are you asking exactly? Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Well clearly that does not work, I spend all my days on Mozilla Developer Network and lots of other sites. How to accept those elements in currencies array to be used for choosing which currency to be exchange to what. I got the JSON data back now i need to bind the array with the selectors so that when i choose EURO or USD to work I have clearly mistakes below the fetch data
I am sure this is the problem starts from below the fetching the data till the end of JavaScript file @AluanHaddad

Comment: @EmirMustafoski Sorry, that is exceedingly broad. Like I said, you code looks better than I would expect, given what you say regarding your experience level, but you have made some mistake as you suggest. I just don't know what it is. The only thing that jumps out at me is that the `currencies` variable means like 4 different things in different places. One place it is an array, somewhere else it has `value` property. Beyond that, "clearly does not work" is unactionably broad.